# Could not create the java virtual machine When I add vm arguments -XX: +UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder

Tags: eclipse, profiling

When I add VM arguments -XX: +UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder for tomcat run configurations in eclipse, I get 'could not create the java virtual machine' error.

What is the way of adding jvm arguments for flight recording ?

Comment: Are you certain that those are valid arguments? Can you launch the java.exe from the command line with them?

Comment: I can not launch the java.exe from command line. But as I know these commands are valid to use mission control application of oracle.

Comment: Are the extra spaces after -XX: just a fluke of copy/paste, or real?

Comment: My problem was resolved. I had updated jdk version for 1.7.0_45. Then I restarted my computer and my problem was resolved. Thnak you so much. But I have another problem. --> When my flight recording finished in mission control application, it gives me error :
Could not load events from flight_recording_2013-12-11_11_28_09.jfr
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.ClassGenException: Illegal opcode detected.

Comment: You should open a different question for that.